# Are there any download managers with web interface?

Tags: download-manager

Im new to ubuntu server , im using a personal home server and i want to install a download manager through terminal. On windows i have been using jdownloader on which i was able to use my accounts on "downloading" sites like rapidshare , easybytes etc..

I read that jdownloader can be installed on ubuntu but only via desktop/gui. Is there any download manager like jdownloader but with webinterface? so it will be easy to use?

Thank you

Comment: This answers your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4 41574/web-client-front-end-download-manager "aria2" is what you want.

Comment: JDownloader has a web interface.

Answer (score 1):

Aria2 has a pretty good web gui, http://aria2.sourceforge.net

Scroll down to the bottom of the homepage.